# Error 1054 from database when I am trying to access model in admin panel

Tags: python, django

So I was trying to modify my models a bit and now I can't get rid of this error. I tried to delete all my data, but it doesn't help. I think it has to do with my database, but before, everything used to work fine. I get this error:

(1054, "Unknown column 'courses_course.course_category_id' in 'field list'")

And here are my models:

```html
class StudyProgramme(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    studies_type = models.IntegerField(choices=((0, "Bachelor Studies"),
                                                (1, "Master Studies"),
                                                (2, "PhD Studies"),
                                                (3, "Integrated Studies")))
    duration = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(99)])

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Study Programme"
        verbose_name_plural = 'Study Programmes'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Course(models.Model):
    study_programme = models.ForeignKey('StudyProgramme', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course_category = models.ForeignKey('CourseCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='',
                                        related_name='categories')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ects = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(99)])
    description = models.TextField()
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(99)])
    semester = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, "1"),
                                            (2, "2"),
                                            ), default=None)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=140, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def _get_unique_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.name)
        unique_slug = slug
        num = 1
        while Course.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, num)
            num += 1
        return unique_slug

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self._get_unique_slug()
        super().save()


class CourseCategory(models.Model):
    course_category = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_category


class Lecture(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', related_name='lectures')
    lecture_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    link = models.URLField(blank=True)
    files = models.ManyToManyField('FileUpload', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lecture_title


class FileUpload(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')

    def file_link(self):

        if self.file:
            return "<a href='%s'>download</a>" % (self.file.url,)
        else:
            return "No attachment"

    file_link.allow_tags = True
    file_link.short_description = 'File Download'
```

Comment: Looks like your schema doesn't match your expectations. Did you add a migration for `course_category_id`? Is it new? If so, did you run the migration? You may try deleting the entire database (not just the data but dropping everything) and running all of the migrations from the start on a fresh db.

Comment: What is the command ? manage.py flush doesnt work.

Comment: Try reading the docs on migrations. If you're encountering an error when migrating, try googling it first.

Comment: try to migrate your database. ```python manage.py makemigratons your_app``` then ```python manage.py migrate```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by dropping the database from mysql shell and then recreating it.

Answer (score 0):

After making any change to your **models** you need to run these two commands in order to reflect them to the database.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and

```
python manage.py migrate
```

reflecting your model class to the database is a two-step process.
Learn more about migrations from [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#workflow).